# How to choose the space of optimal substructures for dynamic programming algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am reading up dynamic programming chapter of [Introduction to Algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/) by Cormen et al. I am trying to understand how to characterize the space of subproblems . They gave two examples of dynamic programming . Both these two problems have an input of size n

1. Rod cutting problem (Cut the rod of size n optimally)
2. Matrix parenthesization problem .(Parenthesize the matrix product A<sub>1</sub> . A<sub>2</sub> .A<sub>3</sub> ...A<sub>n</sub> optimally to get the least number of scalar multiplications)

For the first problem , they choose a subproblem of the form where they make a cut of length k , **assuming that the left subproblem resulting from the cut can not be cut any further** and **the right subproblem can be cut further**  thereby giving us a single subproblem of size (n-k) .

But for the second problem that choose subproblems of the type A<sub>i</sub>...A<sub>j</sub> where 1<=i<=j<=n . Why did they choose to keep both ends open for this problem ? Why not close one end and just consider on subproblems of size (n-k)? Why need both i and j here instead of a single k split?

Comment: In the cut rod problem you can have a first rod of length > 1, so it's ok to suppose a fixed length for the first half of the problem (obviously you'll have to compute the optimal value of k). In the matrix parenthesization problem both the subproblems are composite: you cannot just say "I'll cut here, and for the first half we are done", because you'll need to parenthisize all the way down in the first half, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an art. There are many types of dynamic programming problems, and it is not easy to define one way to work out what dimensions of space we want to solve sub-problems for.

It depends on how the sub-problems interact, and very much on the size of each dimension of space.

Dynamic programming is a general term describing the caching or memoization of sub-problems to solve larger problems more efficiently. But there are so many different problems that can be solved by dynamic programming in so many different ways, that I cannot explain it all, unless you have a specific dynamic programming problem that you need to solve.

All that I can suggest is to try when solving a problem is:

- if you know how to solve one problem, you can use similar techniques for similar problems.
- try different approaches, and estimate the order of complexity (in time and memory) in terms of input size for each dimension, then given the size of each dimension, see if it executes fast enough, and within memory limits.

Some algorithms that can be described as dynamic programming, include:

- shortest path algorithms ([Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), ...)
- string algorithms ([longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), ...)
- and [much more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Algorithms_that_use_dynamic_programming)...

Comment: I am not asking about dynamic programming . I understand how it works but wanted to know if there is  some kind of thumb rule in choosing the space of optimal substructures

Comment: No general rule of thumb can be given without more information about the general nature of the problem. It's like integration, there's a different rule for each type of formula.

Comment: @Geek he wrote about that. It's an art. There's no way to define a general approach. The thumb rule you ask for is the following: "read and understand a lot of solutions written by someone else. Gain experience. Search for similarity between your problem and the ones you learned about. Steal ideas from famous dynamic approach solutions to well-known promblems". There's nothing else :)

Answer (score 2):

Vazirani's technical note on Dynamic Programming 
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf  has some useful ways create subproblems given an input. I have added some other ways to the list below:

1. Input x_1, x_2, ..x_n. Subproblem is x_1...x_i.
2. Input x_1, x_2....x_n. Subproblem is x_i, ...x_j.
3. Input x_1, x_2...x_n and y_1, y_2..y_m. Subproblem is x_1, x_2, ..x_i and y_1, y_2, ..y_j.
4. Input is a rooted tree. Subproblem is a rooted subtree.
5. Input is a matrix. Subproblem is submatrices of different lengths that share a corner with the original matrix.
6. Input is a matrix. Subproblem is all possible submatrices.

Which subproblems to use usualy depends on the problem. Try out these known variations and see which one suits your needs the best.